Help with creating postgres databases with - in the name
I'm currently trying to script some migration of databases on a server.
As part of this process I will need to create a new database with a similar name to the existing database.
Whilst I have this working for the majority of cases I have come across a problem when the name contains the character - in them e.g.
sample-database-name

My script will execute the following command
psql -c "CREATE DATABASE sample-database-name WITH TEMPLATE = template0;"

Which leads to the following error message

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE sample-database-name WITH TEMPLATE = templat...

I believe this is due to the - in the name as others without this work fine, so is there a way to escape the the database name in the command to allow these names to be passed in from the script?  Ideally I'm looking for a solution which I doesn't require me to check for problematic characters and simply make the name as escaped in some fashion.
UPDATE:
This is the function in the script that handles the database creation call
create_new_database() {
    local old_db=$1
    local new_db="${old_db}_new"
    psql -c "CREATE DATABASE $new_db WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8';"
}


You can also use createdb client application for creating database using shell.

You need ro escape the database name or simply don't use such characters
psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE "sample-database-name" WITH TEMPLATE = template0;"

Your command in bash  would look like  where you have to escape the double quotes
create_new_database() {
    local old_db=$1
    local new_db="${old_db}_new"
    psql -c "CREATE DATABASE \"$new_db\" WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8';"
}


Thank you for this and yes this works from the command line, but doesn't actually solve the issue when running in a script.  My apologies I should have provided the script function to give you full context (which I've updated the original post to include now).  I tried ```psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE "$new_db" WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = "UTF8" LC_COLLATE = "en_US.UTF-8" LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8";'


@Mr-F psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE "'$new_db'" WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = "UTF8" LC_COLLATE = "en_US.UTF-8" LC_CTYPE = "en_US.UTF-8";'

@Mr-F  i added you bash command  with escaped double quotes
